# Efficiently retrieving and filtering files by using filename

Tags: c#

i am a newbie hier, i try to retreive files by using  filenames, which have the following definition:

Items number + Revision + lot number.pdf

For example:

- 1109093-A2 (85806S).pdf
- 1109093-A3 (85806S).pdf
- 1109092-A1 (85806S).pdf
- 1109092-A2 (85806S).pdf

for this sample file: 1109093-A2 (85806S).pdf

- Items number: 1109093
- Revision: -A2
- End item number: (85806S)

for my search result, i am supose to have only this files.

- 1109093-A3 (85806S).pdf
- 1109092-A2 (85806S).pdf

  i must have only files,  with the actual Revision like the one up there( A3 ,A2).
- But it not, still now i am getting all Files, how can i sort it by Revision please???

A1, A2, A3, A.... (Revisions) represents the selection criteria  I should use. I wrote the follow function for this job.

```
private string[] GetFiles()
{
    strSourcePath = textBox1.Text;
    strTargetPath = textBox2.Text;
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    strExtension =  "*).pdf";
    string[] files = null;

    if (Directory.Exists(strSourcePath))
    {
        files = Directory.GetFiles(strSourcePath, strExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories); 

        var Result = "";

        string joined = String.Join("# ", Result);
        files = null;

        Result = joined.Split('#'); 
        files = Result.Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file), "^[0-9]+")).ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Source path does not exist!");
    }

    return files ;
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Well done, you can write code in c#. Why are you sharing it?

Answer (score 0):

After you got the paths, you can parse the filename, extract revision/etc and sort based on your criteria.

This code parse as an anonymous class (for readability) and sort based on ItemNumber, Revision.

The anonymous class contains the path and item number/revision/end number info.

See the demo for complete example

```
var paths = new [] {
    "1109093-A2 (85806S).pdf",
    "1109093-A3 (85806S).pdf",
    "1109092-A1 (85806S).pdf",
    "1109092-A2 (85806S).pdf", 
};

var result = paths.Select(x => {
        var match = Regex.Match(x, @"(?<ItemsNumber>\d+)-(?<Revision>\w+)\s+\((?<EndItemNumber>\w+)\).pdf");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return new { ItemNumber = match.Groups[1].Value, Revision = match.Groups[2].Value, EndItemNumber = match.Groups[3].Value, Path = x };
        }
        else {
            return new { ItemNumber = "", Revision = "", EndItemNumber = "", Path = x };
        }
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.ItemNumber).ThenBy(x => x.Revision);
```

demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/47uZni

Comment: Thx for the post, i try your code,the file are sort by Revision Ascending, but i need is only the File with the current Revision its mean the result of my filter muss be:"1109093-A3 (85806S).pdf" and "1109092-A2 (85806S).pdf" because the two files have the highest Revision(A3 und A2)

Comment: updated https://dotnetfiddle.net/47uZni , just use ``.GroupBy(x => x.ItemNumber).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Revision).First());``

Comment: hey using your template i wrote this function, but the return value is allways the same, i dont know why, did you have some idea???

Comment: @Enciro did you have an idea? i am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using your template I wrote this function, but the return value is always the same - one item, but not a list as I expected. I do not know why. Did you have some idea?

```
 private string[] SortFileName(string []TemP)
    {
        var paths = GetTheFileName(TemP);
        List<string> TheCollection = new List<string>();

        var result = paths.Select(x => {
            var match = Regex.Match(x, @"(?<ItemsNumber>\d+)-(?<Revision>\w+)\s+\((?<EndItemNumber>\w+)\).pdf");
            if (match.Success)
            {
                return new { ItemNumber = match.Groups[1].Value, Revision = match.Groups[2].Value, EndItemNumber = match.Groups[3].Value, Path = x };
            }
            else {
                return new { ItemNumber = "", Revision = "", EndItemNumber = "", Path = x };
            }
        })
        .GroupBy(x => x.ItemNumber)
        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Revision).First());

            foreach (var item in result)
            {

                TheCollection.Add(item.Path.ToString());

            }

    return TheCollection.ToArray();
    }
```

PS:  `GetTheFileName(TemP);` return an array with more than 130 items. thanks for the coming help.

Comment: seem ok to me, i tried it (with a little clean up) in https://dotnetfiddle.net/u9k4Kg . Anyway, can you add an example GetTheFileName() item? path is a full path ( ``c:\path\to\file.txt`` or only filename ``file.txt`` )?

Comment: Hey Enrico, first of all thx for your help, i add your example in my code, but the return value still be only the first Items of my Array, not more, may be because: GetTheFileName(TemP) give a dynamic initialised array? Really funny.

Comment: the function GetTheFileName(TemP), return a full path as item.

Comment: try do get filename for regex
``string filename = Path.GetFileName(x);``
updated https://dotnetfiddle.net/u9k4Kg with fix. 
Anyway can you add the list of paths? maybe regex doesnt work right

Comment: Hey Enrico, it is true, regex was not working right. modify it, i give with debuger on life time, and saw that filename in this format:"1107359 - A02 (2-Pin-Konnektor).pdf","1109042 - A02 (E7927).PDF","1109102 - A01 (85915S hellblau).pdf" was not matching, how can i modify the regex, concerning this kind of file?

Comment: updated https://dotnetfiddle.net/u9k4Kg with new regex, you can use ``@"(?<ItemsNumber>\d+)\s*-\s*(?<Revision>\w+)\s+\((?<EndItemNumber>\w.*?)\).[p|P][d|D][f|F]"`` this ignore case on file extension, white space between parts, and allow white space (any character) between ( and ) on EndItemNumber part